# How to schedule Sidekiq Woker.perform.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduled-tasks, sidekiq

I have a worker with one perform class. In the controller I am calling up that worker class. When I call it up with `worker.perform.now` I see in console that perform method is being executed as I want it.

How to schedule this callup in controller, to be performed every day at ten o'clock?

PS: When I call `worker.perform_async` it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PS: When I call worker.perform_async it doesn't do anything.

I guess, that you didn't start sidekiq server. Type `sidekiq` in console to start the server.

As it goes for scheduling sidekiq jobs to perform every period of time, there are several ways to do it.

The one recomended by the Sidekiq's author is to use `CRON` with [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. He even provide and example here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/scheduling.rb

Other way is to use [Sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron) gem. I've found it easier to setup, but it emulates `CRON`, that's why the first solution is more solid.

Comment: Remember to call `bundle exec sidekiq` if you are working in an environment that has a few different versions of sidekiq installed

Comment: also make sure that your `redis-server` is running as well.

Comment: Everything is set good on server.
I have set schedule.rb as suggested by Whenever documentation
`every 1.day, :at => '2:30 pm' do runner "Worker.perform_async" end `

now in cron file I have:
`30 14 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/myapp/current/ && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Worker.perform_async'\''' `

But I still don't have enqueued jobs in sidekiq. 
Do you see something wrong with my cron file?

Comment: Log into your server and run: `/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/user/myapp/current/ && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Worker.perform_async'\'''` in command line. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Actually no. When I run command like that, I see in Sidekiq dashboard that job is processed. I went into my cron file and copied exact command, excluding the time.

Comment: So the command itself is correct. Maybe `CRON` is not running? Check status of `CRON` and start it, if it's not running. There are different ways to do it, depending on operation system.

Comment: So the solution was this:

`30 14 * * * (/bin/bash -l -c 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /home/user/myapp/current/ && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production Worker.perform_async')`